# Link directories in CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, symlink

I am on a CentOS server and I have a user called `theowner`, so he has his folder under `/home/theowner`.

I have two other folders, `f1` and `f2`, under `/home/myprojects/src`, and I want that these folders appears under `/home/theowner`.  I don't want to move the folders but link them to `/home/theowner`.

It's for c9 workspace, and I just want to allow `theowner` to access those folders directly when he logs in.

Comment: `ln -s /home/myprojects/src/f1 /home/theowner/f1`; same for `f2`.  Since you're traversing across multiple users' homes, you'll have to ensure directory and file permissions will permit `theowner` to read them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @DopeGhoti recommended in his comment, what you are wanting is a symbolic link. You can run the following commands as root or with `sudo` to accomplish the task:

```
ln -s /home/myprojects/src/f1 /home/theowner/f1
ln -s /home/myprojects/src/f2 /home/theowner/f2
```

Keep in mind that the file permissions in `f1` and `f2` must allow `theowner` to read, write, and/or execute as you'd like him to be able to do.